# Interprocess communication from SQL Server Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wcf, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to create a SQL Server CLR user-defined function that connects to a 3rd-party service (hosted on the same server as the SQL Server instance).  Is there a way to get WCF named pipes or TCP to work in this situation?  Is there a better way to do this, if I provide an intermediary service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't implement IPC in SQLCLR. The SQL server hosted CLR uses SQL [threading primitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176043.aspx) and you'll end up starving the SQL worker threads and schedulers.

Do all your IPC from a process outside SQL Server. If you need to communicate with this process from SQL jobs (from stored procedures and triggers) use in-database queuing, either by [Tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) or by [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Why would IPC be any worse than any other use of SQLCLR?

Comment: Because it makes the current process (sqlservr.exe) block waiting for other process response. Since SQL is a cooperative user-mode multi-threading environment, these external blocks stall all SQL processing.

Comment: So it's a matter of the amount of time IPC takes?

Comment: No. It's a matter of doing *anything* IPC. SQLCLR is not the proper avenue for that.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm a bit slow in understanding here.  Why is IPC inherently any worse than any other bit of SQLCLR that takes time to complete?  Or does SQLCLR get processed in a special way to play nicely with the cooperative multitasking?

Comment: Primarily because of the unpredictability of failures when IPC is involved. Every combination of SQLCLR+IPC I've seen (and I've seen a few) ended up a meltdown disaster in production under even mild load. The factors that add up are too complex to describe here, they involve the nature of SQL threading, going preemptive in SQL schedulers and CLR managed threading, and I reckon I don't know *all* the interactions involved, but I understand enough to make a very strong recommendation to avoid this. The gist is that the server ends up with all workers stolen and blocked in CLR wait events.

Comment: Remus Rusanu: Could you clarify if your recommendation is mainly related to the issue of using IPC from SQL-CLR or IPC with SQL Server in general. I mean, if you implement IPC using extended stored proc written in C/C++ (instead of C#), would it be subject to the same concern?

Comment: @AlekDavis: afaik XPs are executed in preemptive mode. SQLCLR is executed in cooperative mode, at least until they call [`BeginThreadAffinity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity.aspx). Preemptive mode fixes some of the issues, so XPs are somewhat better. But still, if you can avoid IPC from XPs, avoid it. If you do IPC from a trigger consider using a message queue, insert in the queue from trigger and let an external process handle the IPC, *after* the trigger xact committed.