# CLR function calls a remote SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I am totally new to SQL Server CLR. I understand that we should use CLR under the condition that business logic is really complicated to implement in SQL.

We have quite a few functions in VB.NET to process data, such as standardizing data. I am trying to implement them through CLR. The functions access a remote server first to get some reference data, then process on the local server.

However no matter how I try, I got Error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

or it returns null from the remote server.

Can we access a remote server in the CLR routine? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access remote servers in the .Net CLR **but you really shouldn't**.

SQL server operates in a cooperative multitasking environment, i.e. threads are trusted to terminate and complete their processing (one way or another) in a timely manner.  If you start doing things like calling remote methods (which are liable to long delays) you are likely going to end up starving SQL server worker threads which will ultimately end up with Bad Things happening.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434664/interprocess-communication-from-sql-server-project)

Comment: Kragen, I realized I should use sqlclient library to connect to remote server rather than suing the oledb in CLR. If accessing remote servers is not recommended, is it better to add that server as linked server, then access it?

Comment: @Star If you are trying to access a remote SQL server then yes, linked servers + distributed queries / transactions are definitely the way to go.

Comment: Kragen, thanks. Then I will go toward with linked server. I am not familiar with distributed queries, will do a search on that. Thanks again for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You can use the normal SqlCommand & SqlConnection classes in the .NET framework to do so.=, if the remote servers are SQL Servers, which I assume it is.

If they are web servers, yes you can, use web services.

On a side note. Be very careful what you do in the CLR, because as attractive as CLR looks you only have about 512MB of memory under SQL 2005, and by adding some startup parameters you can push it out to 2Gb. Just be aware.

EDIT:

Based on your comments, I suggest using a linked server, and then re-creating the remote table locally and then joining to it on the local server.

You will have to make sure you re-create indexes and keys on the local box, and for speed -sake, do it after you inserted the records into the table, else building your indexes on an already populated table, will take a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the info. As I mentioned above, I should use sqlclient connection rather than Oledb connection. If accessing remote servers is not recommended, is it better to add that server as linked server, then access it?

Comment: You can use Linked Servers, but they have a big impact on performance, and it is normally hard to fix. If you do distributed queries from SQL to SQL, you should re-think your architecture, maybe you are doing things in places where they are not meant to be done.

Comment: We have reference database on one SQL server and we process projects on different SQL server. To keep the reference database as a repository, what's the best way to do it? We process data on SQL server, not through other other API.

Comment: 1) I would suggest removing the process from SQL server and putting it in a windows service or an external machine that can see both servers. Here you can then get a bit creative on how to do it. You can then pass the references to the processing server, or if it is business logic, perform everything in .NET on a seperate server. *OR* 2) if this is too hard, one way to overcome joining over linked servers (WHICH IS VERY SLOW), you can select the reference table, and create it locally on the processing server and then join to it locally.

Comment: But for speed I will avoid distributed queries over a linked server at all costs. Yes it can do it, and yes documentation says it works, and yes it works, (slowly), but when the going gets tough, and you need speed, this will be the first bottleneck on your process, especially joining columns across a linked server.

Comment: When you say creating the table locally on the processing server, do I just import the reference tables to the processing server from the linkedserver, then join it? That makes sense to me. Yes, speed is vital since we might need to process millions of records.

Comment: Ok, lets say you have Table1 on remote server. 2 options. 1) What I will do is to do a *SELECT * INTO tempdb.dbo.tempTable1 FROM linkedserver.db1.dbo.Table1*, then I will duplicate the Primary Key on the temp table that is local now, and all other required indexes, and then simply join to this table. 2) Create a Physical Copy of the remote table in the local database (including keys and indexes and constraints), then you can truncate everytime and re-populate this table, or you can just copy over the new records using SQL 2008 "EXCEPT" command. I am not sure of the table type of the remote box

Comment: So it is a bit hard, but this will at least give you some guidance. If the remote table is only inserted into, option 2 is what I would go for. That means you will only ever *add* new records locally. Otherwise it can become a bit complex to figure out which needs to be inserted and removed, but very do-able. Else if you have good speed between boxes, and the remote table is updated, inserted, deleted from, I would just temporarily re-create it everytime and then use it. I hope this helps.